# Check if a polygon is at one elevation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, elevation

I have a polygon (pond) and I need to ensure it is at one elevation. I have converted all vertices of the polygon to points, used summary statistics to determine the range in elevations and if the range is greater than 0, it indicates there is a discrepancy in elevation values. I do not have spatial analyst or 3D analyst. Is there an easier way or code to do this in ArcGIS?  I received this layer from a fellow employee that extracted the data from a LiDAR point cloud using MicroStation. Therefore, I do not have the original elevation (raster) layer, just a shapefile that has elevation values attached to the vertices. I am looking for a way to identify a polygon whose vertices have different elevation values. Each polygon should have one elevation value associated with each vertice. For example, Polygon A should have a 120m elevation value for each vertice in the polygon. I am looking for something to check if the vertices are different.

Comment: What attribute are you calculating the range on? Does they polygon have a z value?

Comment: Your question has been asked before The intersect point with raster tool is this one:
http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/isectpntrst.htm Previous answers
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28298/how-to-extract-raster-dem-elevations-to-vector-attribute-tables-in-arcgis-10

Comment: I used ET Geowizards to convert the vertices to points. A field called ET_Z shows the elevation values.

Answer (score 5):

This works without SA or 3D

```py
import arcpy, traceback, sys
##, numpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

pntFile=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
rasters=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
rasters=rasters.split(';')
theFields=arcpy.ListFields(pntFile)
theFields=[x.name.lower() for x in theFields]
result=arcpy.GetCount_management(pntFile)
nF=int(result.getOutput(0))
p=arcpy.Point()
try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    arcpy.AddMessage('\n')
    for raster in rasters:
                desc=arcpy.Describe(raster)
                theFLD=raster.lower()
                arcpy.AddMessage("Sampling "+theFLD)
                if not(theFLD in theFields):
                        arcpy.AddField_management(pntFile, theFLD, "FLOAT")
                arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "", 0, nF)
                with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pntFile,("SHAPE@XY",theFLD)) as rows:
                        for row in rows:
                                XY=row[0]
                                p.X,p.Y=XY
                                myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster,p,1,1,-9999)
                                row[1]=myArray[0,0]
                                rows.updateRow(row)
                                arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
                        del row,rows
    arcpy.AddMessage('\n')
except NameError, theMessage:
    arcpy.AddMessage (theMessage)
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Script works from mxd. Parameters are point layer (shapefile) and list of rasters:

[image: Script Tool Interface]

Comment: forgot to mention. Make raster layer(s) name short, e.g. Lidar, because script creates same name field in point layer table and populates it with raster values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I received this layer from a fellow employee that extracted the data from a LiDAR point cloud using MicroStation. Therefore, I do not have the original elevation (raster) layer, just a shapefile that has elevation values attached to the vertices. I am looking for a way to identify a polygon whose vertices have different elevation values. Each polygon should have one elevation value associated with each vertice. For example, Polygon A should have a 120m elevation value for each vertice in the polygon. I am looking for something to check if the vertices are different.

Comment: Use feature to point if you have advanced license. This should produce pointZ with polygon ID. You can summarise polygon ID to find StDev for Z and check if it is close to zero