# In ArcGIS 10.x, how do I select features of a point shapefile whose z values are above or below the elevations in a DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, select, select-by-attribute

I have a multi-point shapefile representing earthquake hypocenters (containing depth values) and I have a DEM raster representing an underground surface (the top of the PreCambrian basement). I want to select only the points whose depth values are greater than the elevations in the DEM. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you running? Do you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: I am running 10.3 and have access to Spatial Analyst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start to this (quoted from source):

...There's a tool at Spatial Analyst Tools\Extraction\Extract Multi Values to Points and Extract Values to Points. Extract Multi Values to Points is better because it lets you rename the z field name that you are extracting your values to—Extract Values to Points doesn't let you do this. I have trouble doing this in ArcMap (the tool crashes), but it works fine in ArcCatalog.

quoted from: [Extracting raster DEM elevations to vector attribute tables in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28298/how-to-extract-raster-dem-elevations-to-vector-attribute-tables-in-arcgis-10)

Once you have the dem data in the point file attribute tables, create a new field named like Elev_Diff and use the field calculator to calcuate the values.  Then you can use a def query or select by attributes to only select the negative values.